# How to forward port 443 on C1100T wifi router

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to forward port 443 on the wifi router that CenturyLink gave me. It's a technicolor C1100T router. When I try to forward port 443, I get the following error message:

*The defined port or port range is in use by another port forwarding or application rule.*

I didn't add that port before (so it's not a dupe) and don't see it elsewhere on a page in the router setup. I had that port forwarded on my old router and it's important for my phone and other devices to be able to connect to my mail server.

Comment: check to see if the port is open on canyouseeme.org, its common for this port to be used for remote administration (HTTPS). i would be willing to bet its currently in use by the router your trying to configure.

Comment: Using "canyouseeme.org", I get:"Error: I could not see your service on [my.ip.address] on port (443) Reason: Connection refused" So, what does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Port 443 was already taken by the router's Remote GUI Management. To free up that port:

1. Log in to the wifi router.
2. Go into the Advanced section.
3. Click on Remote GUI on the left side menu under Remote Management.
4. Enable Remote GUI and change the port to something other than 443 (such as 4433), then Save.
5. Disable Remote GUI if you don't want it enabled, then Save.

Comment: Lol, so it was indeed being used by the router... I will delete the answer

Comment: Yeah. Guess I hadn't looked thoroughly enough. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: You are welcome. Probably should have put my money on it ;)