# Can't forward port 443 on C1100T wifi router

Tags: router, wireless-router, port-forwarding

I have the same problem as outlined in this question:

[How to forward port 443 on C1100T wifi router](https://superuser.com/questions/1292712/how-to-forward-port-443-on-c1100t-wifi-router)

After making the changes outlined in the answer, I still get that same error message when trying to forward port 443.

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the error in?

Comment: Since this seems to be a reoccurring issue (i.e. the trouble with port forwarding port 443), you may (possibly) want to consider trying to put the C1100T in Bridged Mode (Transparent Bridging) in conjunction with another router. That way, the C1100T wouldn't be the device handling port forwarding (it would act as "just" a modem). Obviously this would require a separate router and possibly contacting Century Link and asking for your PPPoE username and password.